# ZSH - pyenv 'command not found' on login or new window - works on load.

Tags: python, terminal, zsh, pyenv

I'm using ZSH/oh-my-zsh and the regular OSX terminal, though the same problem occurs in iTerm. I'd been using `rbenv` and `nvm` without issue, but recently started working with python and `pyenv`, and have run into the following issue. On loading a new terminal window, I get the following message at the prompt:

```
Last login: Sat Apr  1 11:56:46 on ttys001
/Users/jackfuller/.zshenv:3: command not found: pyenv
```

Since installing `pyenv`, my machine seems noticeably slower. Obviously loading `pyenv` will slow things down but load times have dropped way off.

The catch is that `pyenv` works perfectly after the terminal is loaded, and as far as I can tell my `.zshrc` is configured properly:

```
alias dev="cd ~/development"
alias gow="cd ~/goworkspace"
alias dl="cd ~/downloads"

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH

export EDITOR='atom -n'
export PAGER='less -f'

export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH
RBENV
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

# NVM
export NVM_DIR="/Users/jackfuller/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm



# PYENV
export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/pyenv
eval "$(pyenv init - --no-rehash)"
# if which pyenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv init - --no-rehash)"; 
   fi


# For go.
export GOPATH="$HOME/goworkspace"
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOROOT="usr/local/go"
```

If anyone can offer any advice/solutions, it would be much appreciated. Environment variables and shell config files seem more temperamental /confusing than they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Users/jackfuller/.zshenv:3: command not found: pyenv` indicates that your error is in .zshenv at line 3. Maybe you could post your `.zshenv`. Is there a reason the `fi` after `#PYENV` is not commented? Also you could do `export PATH=...` once and not thrice. Try `which pyenv` to find the path to `pyenv` and look if its in your `$PATH`. For Future uses i'd put my aliases into `~/.zsh_aliases` and do a `source ~/.zsh_aliases` in the `.zshrc`, otherwise it gets pretty ugly once you have some more aliases. Sorry for the bad structured answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer- uncommenting the following
 `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` from my `zshenv` seems to have removed the error. 


The `fi` was a formatting error in the question, now fixed.

Comment: You're welcome. Is the problem solved,  if yes then could you mark answer as solution?

Comment: Will do! Also the separate alias thing is a good idea, I'll get on it.